# How to write URL with parameters for BItrix24 Rest API?

Tags: json, url, get, rest, bitrix

I mam trying bitrix rest api on localhost. As i wanted to request bizprocess tasks using api from the url but it is returning only by default value in the para meters Here is link to the page https://training.bitrix24.com/rest_help/workflows/workflows_tasks/bizproc_task_list.php. In
the page it has given lot of parameters we can request so please help me to write these parameters in the url
MY URL = https://b24-6dil6a.bitrix24.com/rest/bizproc.task.list.xml?auth=ce782c610056ed050056ed0100000001282303d5d786cc952d4b7e2bf51a6f12fe4bfd.

Also if i do like this = https://b24-6dil6a.bitrix24.com/rest/bizproc.task.list.json?ACTIVITY&auth=ce782c610056ed050056ed0100000001282303d5d786cc952d4b7e2bf51a6f12fe4bfd

still there is no change in returned value.

Comment: https://domain_B24.bitrix24.{ru|com|de}/rest/name_method.transport?parameters_method&auth=authorization_key   This is documented format in which api should be requested

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no code ....